# how to disable status or notification bar for android activities

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-notification-bar

I have referred many solutions but using that my app crashes

I am using custom theme as I am using custom action bar

this is the code which I am using the style

```
 <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Also using below code crashes my app

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: can you post the logcat

Answer (score 0):

You should use this before `setContentView`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else
{
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

Comment: I am using customtheme so my theme is    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"

Comment: Yes,I had added this before setContentView only in my activity.

Comment: please post the logcat